# NodeJS Promise Map didn't waiting for Sequelize Query

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get data using sequelize inside a map with Promise.

Here is my code:

```
const userTypeList = ["Adult","Teen"];
const userData = [];

await Promise.all(
    userTypeList.map(async (type) => {
      console.log("Value: ", type);

      const selectedCount = await model[`User${type}`].count({
        where: conditions,
      });

      const comparisonCount = await model[`User${type}`].count({
        where: pastConditions,
      });


      console.log("Go Next Iterate...")
      userData.push({selected: selectedCount, comparison: comparisonCount});
    })
);
```

I can't get the issue clearly, it just print the `console.log` in the beginning of iteration for each index, but didn't execute/skip the sequelize query and the `console.log()` at the end of iteration.

Here is my console result:
[image]

Comment: `model[`User${type}`]` this is null, first, you need fix this.

Comment: what is output of `console.log(model)` ?